# How to fix the facebook like button bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, facebook-like

I'm developing my first website and I have a problem with the Facebook  like button, from the Facebook developer section,The bug can be seen in the video below https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9k6CL4qGqw
Every time when I click on the "Like" button
the button change Place.
HOW TO FIX IT ??

```
<div id="menu">
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA-%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%AA-1529931987323926/?pnref=story" data-width="10px" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>

        <ul>
            <li><h2><a href="/HtmlPage1.html">ראשי</a></h2></li>
            <li><h2><a href="/אודות.html">אודות</a></h2></li>
            <li><h2><a href="צור קשר.html">צור קשר</a></h2></li>

        </ul>

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you link to 'Facebook developer section'?  Is this all of your code?  You tag javascript but only show snippet of html